# Как получить доступ к свойствам дочернего класса после десериализации

Tags: c#

Есть 1 базовый класс:

```
class Base
{
}
```

Есть 2 дочерних класса:

```
class A : Base
{
    string Type { get; set; } = nameof(string);
    override string ToString() => nameof(A);
}

class B : Base
{
    string Type { get; set; } = nameof(int);
    override string ToString() => nameof(B);
}
```

Есть класс, который необходимо сериализовать:

```
[Serialuzation]
class ExampleSerialize
{
    public List<Base> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Реализация:

```
static void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    
    var exmp = new ExampleSerialize();
    exmp.Data.Add(a);
    exmp.Data.Add(b);
}
```

Вопрос: как правильно сериализовать класс `ExampleSerialize` в json, чтобы потом этот json можно было корректно десериализовать обратно в этот класс и получить информацию из классов `A` и `B`

P.S. Если подскажите корректное название для этого вопроса - буду крайне признателен. Не знаю, как правильно описать проблему, с которой столкнулся

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании - "дочерних класса"? Унаследованных от Base? - так не видно

Comment: @Виктор Виноват, не заметил. Поправил

Comment: Какой сериализатор используете? [Type Hierarchies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#type-hierarchies)

Comment: Использую `System.Text.Json`. Про этот атрибут впервые читаю. Для сериализации использую просто `JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj)`

Comment: Читать файл в переменную jsonString, а потом ExampleSerialize results = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExampleSerialize>(jsonString); - вроде так

Comment: Возможно надо [Serialize] class Base